# Typescript / React: how to construct an object with key: value as [string]: [ReactComponent]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to export an object with keys as one of a union of strings and values as one of a union of React Components. There are no errors but there are issues with my code:

```js
import ReceiveCall from './ReceiveCall';
import RateApp from './RateApp';

const EmptyChild = <p>Empty Modal</p>;
const EmptyChildTwo = <p>Empty Modal</p>;

type modalKeys = 'rateApp' | 'receiveCall' | 'empty';
type modalValue = typeof ReceiveCall | typeof RateApp | typeof EmptyChild;

type modalTypeMap = { [type in modalKeys]: modalValue };

const modalComponents: modalTypeMap = {
  receiveCall: ReceiveCall,
  rateApp: RateApp,
  empty: EmptyChildTwo
};

export default modalComponents;
```

I am trying to build the object so that the value of the key/value pair is either `ReceiveCall | RateApp | EmptyChild` but my code is really just doing the following:

`type modalValue = JSX.Element | (() => JSX.Element) | (() => JSX.Element)`

For example, `EmptyChildTwo` should throw an error because it's not present in the `modalValue` type. How do I communicate to typescript that the value must be either `ReceiveCall | RateApp | EmptyChild` and not just a JSX.Element or a function that returns a JSX.Element?